# LibGDX how to efficiently handle button presses

Tags: libgdx, input

I'm making a simple 2D game for android using LibGDX. My game needs to have many buttons in it that fire off a method when pressed, and I was wondering what the best way to do this would be.

I tried a simple solution using an InputProcessor and a bunch of if statements but it seems really unscalable and inefficient. Here's my attempt:

```
InputProcessor inputProcessor = new InputProcessor() {
        @Override
        public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
          //  message = "Touch down: " + screenX + ", " + screenY;
            if (screenY >= 2280) {
                if(screenX >= 31 && screenX <= 281) {
                    yellowButtonPressed = true;
                } else if(screenX >= 313 && screenX <= 563) {
                    redButtonPressed = true;
                } else if(screenX >= 595 && screenX <= 845) {
                    blueButtonPressed = true;
                } else if(screenX >= 877 && screenX <= 1127) {
                    greenButtonPressed = true;
                } else if(screenX >= 1159 && screenX <= 1409) {
                    orangeButtonPressed = true;
                } else {
                    //regular click
                    if (monster.isAlive()) {
                        monster.takeDamage(1);
                    }
                }


            } else if(screenY <= 1690 && screenY >= 1510 && screenX <= 1430 && screenX >= 1280) {
                    xPressed = true;

            } else {

                    //regular click
                    if (monster.isAlive()) {
                        monster.takeDamage(1);
                    }

                }

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
     //       message = "Touch up: " + screenX + ", " + screenY;
            if(yellowButtonPressed) {
                if(screenX >= 31 && screenX <= 281) {
                    xButton.show();
                    menuShown = true;
                    tempCurrentMenu = "Heroes";
                }
                yellowButtonPressed = false;
            } else if(redButtonPressed) {
                if(screenX >= 313 && screenX <= 563) {
                    xButton.show();
                    menuShown = true;
                    tempCurrentMenu = "Fighters";
                }
                redButtonPressed = false;
            } else if(blueButtonPressed) {
                if(screenX >= 595 && screenX <= 845) {
                    xButton.show();
                    menuShown = true;
                    tempCurrentMenu = "Researchers";
                }
                blueButtonPressed = false;
            } else if(greenButtonPressed) {
                if(screenX >= 877 && screenX <= 1127) {
                    xButton.show();
                    menuShown = true;
                    tempCurrentMenu = "Artifacts";
                }
                greenButtonPressed = false;
            } else if(orangeButtonPressed) {
                if(screenX >= 1159 && screenX <= 1409) {
                    xButton.show();
                    menuShown = true;
                    tempCurrentMenu = "Purchases";
                }
                orangeButtonPressed = false;
            } else if(xPressed) {
                if(screenY <= 1690 && screenY >= 1510 && screenX <= 1430 && screenX >= 1280) {
                    menuShown = false;
                    xButton.hide();
                    tempCurrentMenu = "";
                }
                xPressed = false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
            return false;
        }
    };
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A much better option is to create a small class (or reuse a suitable one like Rectangle) and keep them in a list, the code becomes simpler and it will be easy to add more buttons over time.

```
InputProcessor inputProcessor = new InputProcessor() {

  private final static List<Button> buttons = ...
  private Button lastButton = null;

  abstract class Button {
    public final int top, left, bottom, right;
    public boolean isHit(int x, int y) {
      return top <= y && bottom >= y && left <= x && right >= x;
    }
    public void doClick() {}
    public boolean performDrag() { return false; }
  }

  public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    for (Button b : buttons) {
      if (b.isHit(screenX, screenY) {
        b.doClick();
        lastButton = b;
        return true;
      }
    }
    // No button was clicked, perform other checks
  }
  public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    if (lastButton.performDrag(screenX, screenY)) {
      lastButton = null;
      return true;
    }
    lastButton = null;
    // Button didn't accept the drag gesture, check other things
  }
}
```

As you can see Button has doClick and performDrag that can be overridden in the classes for each specific button, as an example for your yellow button

```
class YellowButton extends Button {
  @override
  public boolean performDrag() {
    if(screenX < 31 || screenX > 281)
      return false;

    xButton.show();
    menuShown = true;
    tempCurrentMenu = "Heroes";
    return true;          
  }
}
```

Another thing is that you could implement doClick as `boolean doClick(x,y)` instead of having an `isHit` function to check with first, in the same way as the `performDrag` function works, whichever way you feel more comfortable with. In this case I made it two functions mostly because then you don't need to implement the coordinate checkup in your specific button classes.

Comment: Thanks! This was really helpful. I had one more question, what is the point of returning true or false in all of the input methods?

Comment: @mongy910 You mean in touchUp/-Down? It's to signal that your application knew what the gesture meant and made use of it, I'm afraid I don't know exactly why this is necessary in this situation, but usually it's to prevent other controls from receiving the input; parent containers, or possibly even iOs itself.